# UIView with rounded corners, but content is not rounded

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

I have a UIView, inside this UIVIew I have an other view that has almost the same size as his parent. The parent view needs to have rounded corners, and that works, but the content is not being rounded. Is there a way to wrap the content or something like that?

To round the corners of the parent view this is what I'm doing:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

self.boxView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
```

Here is little sketch of what I'm talking about... (I think this is going to be more self-explanatory)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `self.view.layer.masksToBounds = YES`? Or maybe self.view.clipSubview?

Comment: Put the child behind the "parent" (both inside an owning view)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.boxView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It was easy, but as we say in our country: "He who does not know, is like he who does not see."